# pull string using regex in sas

Tags: regex, sas, extract, text-extraction

I have a string like this:

```
HAHDFKDLFDAFHDKFJL/ABCD//NAME/I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS/JJJJ//NAME/blah blah blah
```

at other time, the string looks like this

```
HAHDFKDLFDAFHDKFJL/ABCD//NAME/I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS
```

I want to pull the string `I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS`

I have regex built to pull the first example, but cannot figure out how to pull the second example (situation when there is no '/' that follows the string I want to pull). How can I tweak the code to be able to pull the second example?

```
re = prxparse('/\/ABCD\/\/NAME\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\//s');
if prxmatch(re, string_data) then 
do;
    extracted_string = prxposn(re, 1, string_data);
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about Perl. Removing that tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can match the end of line with $

```
re = prxparse('/\/ABCD\/\/NAME\/(.*?)$/s');
```

This match the two case:

```
re = prxparse('/\/ABCD\/\/NAME\/(.*?)($|\/)/s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
set test;
re = prxparse('/\/ABCD\/\/NAME\/(.*?)(\/|$)/s');
if prxmatch(re, string_data) then 
do;
    extracted_string = prxposn(re, 1, string_data);
end;
```